# How can I load a specific language on a distribution URL?

Tags: media-manager

A distribution can have a set subtitle and voiceover language. How can I load the distribution URL in my webpage and tell it to use another subtitle and voiceover language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to set the subtitle, voiceover and backslide language in the distribution URL. This way the same distribution URL can be used in multiple webistes, the website will add parameters to the distribution URL to set the language.

A distribution URL looks like this where GUID is the GUID of the distribution. `http://INSTANCEURL/vms/distribution/?o=GUID&sl=EN`

The sl, nl and bl parametes can be set to use a specific language for resp. the subtitles, backslides and voiceover. `http://INSTANCEURL/vms/distribution/?o=GUID&sl=EN&vl=NL&bl=EN`

Also see the manual

- [Localization query string parameters](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_MediaManager_23/task_57487540759344709C37D58C073093A7) (login required)
- [Language codes](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_MediaManager_23/concept_A9F20DF9433C46FF8FED8FA11A29FAA0) (login required)